# Code re-factoring does not give the same result at the end

Tags: java

I am trying to rewrite and re-factor my code below but I do not have the same result at the end(List vgs does not contain the same result when I execute both function).
Also, I can not figure out what is wrong with my code below. Can someone tell me how can do to keep the order of my elements in List andVars, notVars and orVars?
The goal of this function is to remove all null or empty String element values of andVars & notVars list + all duplicate elements in my String element values of andVars & notVars list 
for each varGroup element and keep the order of the elements of andVars, notVars list. Thank you

```
public static void RemoveDuplicateListElements(List<VarGroup> vgs) {
        if (vgs == null) {
            return;
        }
        for (VarGroup vg : vgs) {
            RemoveDuplicateListElements(vg.getOrVars());
            if (vg.getAndVars() != null) {
                for (int x = vg.getAndVars().size()-1 ; x >= 0; x--) {
                    if (vg.getAndVars().get(x) == null
                            || vg.getAndVars().get(x).isEmpty())
                    {
                        vg.getAndVars().remove(x);
                    } else {
                        for (int y = 0; y < x; y++) {
                            if (vg.getAndVars().get(x).equals(vg.getAndVars().get(y))) {
                                vg.getAndVars().remove(x);
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if (vg.getNotVars() != null) {
                for (int x = vg.getNotVars().size()-1 ; x >= 0; x--) {
                    if (vg.getNotVars().get(x) == null
                            || vg.getNotVars().get(x).isEmpty())
                    {
                        vg.getNotVars().remove(x);
                    } else {        
                        for (int y = 0; y < x; y++) {
                            if (vg.getNotVars().get(x).equals(vg.getNotVars().get(y))) {
                                vg.getNotVars().remove(x);
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
public class VarGroup {
    private List<String> notVars = new ArrayList();
    private List<VarGroup> orVars = new ArrayList();
    private List<String> andVars = new ArrayList();

    public List<VarGroup> getOrVs() {
        return this.orVars;
    }
    public void setOrVars(List<VarGroup> orVars) {
        this.orVars = orVars;
    }
    public List<String> getAndVars() {
        return this.andVars;
    }
    public void setAndVars(List<String> andVars) {
        this.andVars = andVars;
    }
    public List<String> getNotVars() {
        return this.notVars;
    }
    public void setNotVars(List<String> notVars) {
        this.notVars = notVars;
    }
}
```

My refactoring is here:

```
public static void RemoveDuplicateListElements(List<VarGroup> vgs) {
    if (vgs == null) {
        return;
    }
    for (VarGroup vg : vgs) {
        RemoveDuplicateListElements(vg.getOrVars());
        if (vg.getAndVars() != null) {
            vg.getAndVars().stream().distinct()
                    .filter(andVar -> Objects.nonNull(andVar) || !andVar.isEmpty())
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
        }

        if (vg.getNotVars() != null) {
            vg.getNotVars().stream().distinct()
                    .filter(notVar -> Objects.nonNull(notVar) || !notVar.isEmpty())
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once.

Comment: (1) Write tests that pass with the original code (2) Refactor step by step and test at each step.

Comment: Also note that your stream operations don't do anything (you collect the result to a list but ignore the returned value)...

Answer (score 2):

This code in your refactored method does not do anything:

```
if (vg.getAndVars() != null) {
    vg.getAndVars().stream().distinct()
                .filter(andVar -> Objects.nonNull(andVar) || !andVar.isEmpty())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

It just creates a stream from the list, filters the stream, and then creates a new list from the filtered stream. But that new list is then immediately discarded. You should use the created filtered list using `setAndVars`, or e.g. using `retainAll` to modify the existing list.

Alternatively, if you want to use streams and lambdas, how about using `removeIf`? You can keep track of duplicates using a `Set`<sup>1)</sup>. Simple example:

```
List<String> lst = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("foo", "bar", "foo", "blub", null));
Set<String> seen = new HashSet<>();
lst.removeIf(x ->  x == null || ! seen.add(x));
```

---

<sup>1)</sup> Usually you should not use methods with side effects in streams.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should extract some function here:

```
public static void removeDuplicateListElements(List<VarGroup> vgs) {
    if (vgs == null) {
        return;
    }
    for (final VarGroup vg : vgs) {
        removeDuplicateListElements(vg.getOrVars());
        handleVars(vg.getAndVars());
        handleVars(vg.getNotVars());
    }
}

private static void handleVars(final List<String> theVars) {
    if (theVars != null) {
        for (int x = theVars.size() - 1; x >= 0; x--) {
            if (theVars.get(x) == null || theVars.get(x).isEmpty()) {
                theVars.remove(x);
            } else {
                for (int y = 0; y < x; y++) {
                    if (theVars.get(x).equals(theVars.get(y))) {
                        theVars.remove(x);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Method used (Intellij Idea):

- select `vg.getAndVars()` and extract a variable for it
- select `vg.getOrVars()` and extract a variable for it
- got a warning about duplicated code
- select the 1st bloc marked as duplicated and extract a method (accept IntelliJ proposal to replace 2nd block)
- inline vars extracted in the 2 first steps
- (Bonus step: some renaming)

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like this code will remove every element of the list

```
for (int x = vg.getAndVars().size()-1 ; x >= 0; x--) {
    // ...
    for (int y = 0; y < x; y++) {
        if (vg.getAndVars().get(x).equals(vg.getAndVars().get(y))) {
            vg.getAndVars().remove(x);
              break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Since you're removing elements from the list in the loop, the data stored in a given index could change during the loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you want duplicates removed and keeping order why don't you use a [TreeSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html)
?

Comment: TreeSet is sorted. If OP used a Set (which I agree, it might be a good idea here), I think they would want LinkedHashSet which is ordered by insertion order. LinkedHashSet would retain the original ordering of the List.